# How do i unpack a docker image into a normal file system to upload to a website host?

Tags: docker

I have just received the files for a website I have accepted to host in a docker image. I have not used docker before and the hosting site i am currently with does not allow for an image to be run on it. I would like to unpack the image files so i could upload to the host normally. I have been learning for a few days but have not found an easy route to unpack the image without having to manually move the files and change the routes linking some of them. What commands would be required to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options:

1. Read the dockerfile and check where the files come from.
   (dockerfile is the recipe to build docker images)
2. If you don't have the dockerfile, you can run the container in your personal machine and copy them. (from the container to your machine)

   `docker cp <container_id>:/foo.txt foo.txt`